# Repair json file without quotes using sed

Tags: json, sed

How could I repair a json file without quotes using sed or perl or whatever shell script tool? That is to add back the double quotes (e.g. "glossary"). Below is the sample json. Thanks a lot!

```
{
    glossary: {
        title: "example glossary",
            GlossDiv: {
                title: "S",
                GlossList: {
                    GlossEntry: {
                        ID: "SGML",
                        SortAs: "SGML",
                        GlossTerm: "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                        Acronym: "SGML",
                        Abbrev: "ISO 8879:1986",
                        GlossDef: {
                            para: "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                            GlossSeeAlso: ["GML", "XML"]
                        },
                    GlossSee: "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please add expected output for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This quick and dirty one-liner works for your example. However your json format must be "pretty-printed" same as your input example. also the attribute names should follow the pattern: `[a-zA-Z_]+`

```
sed -r 's/(\s*)([a-zA-Z_]+)/\1"\2"/' file
```

it outputs:

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
            "GlossDiv": {
                "title": "S",
                "GlossList": {
                    "GlossEntry": {
                        "ID": "SGML",
                        "SortAs": "SGML",
                        "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                        "Acronym": "SGML",
                        "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                        "GlossDef": {
                            "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                            "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                        },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly in my case. Thanks for saving my life!